# How to scroll to the top of a tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, scroll, tinymce

I've a bunch of tinymce editors on a page and they have really large blocks of text. Once the user finishes working on one editor, is there a way to automatically scroll to the top of the (current) editor while the user tabs out and goes to the next editor?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: It should be scrollIntoView (View with capital V)